# 'showSnackBar' and 'flatbutton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used

Tags: flutter

Trying to figure out this flutter problem. The below code has the flatbutton and showSnackbar as deprecated, and am trying to figure out with the fix is.

Any help is appreciated.

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Latihan 2"),
        actions: [
          FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                    content: Text("Anda Menekan Icon Plus"),
                    duration: Duration(seconds: 3)));
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Icon(
                Icons.remove,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the codes that you've used are deprecated. Instead of using showSnackBar, try using ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(). Instead of FlatButton you can use TextButton.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation found [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger) it seems snackbars are now handled by the ScaffoldMessenger.

You can swap FlatButton with TextButton as suggested in the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html)